# Selecting hidden string in Outlook Email & then populating BCC

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a large set of daily reports that are pushed out to individuals via dbmail on a 24 hour loop.

What I'm wanting to do is pick up a string of hidden text (I'd assume this would be programmatically ok to be picked up) from the body of the email & then populate the BCC field when the recipient replies to the given department with sign off of the report contents, I was also going to have this macro run when a custom category is met.

I think a macro would be the way forward, my VBA skills aren't great, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help as ever would be much appreciated.

Cheers
Bob

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question is too broad for this site. Try something, get stuck on a *specific* problem (after researching it), and then you'll have something we can chew on. At this point all you have is specifications; Stack Overflow won't write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

this answer falls outside of the rules of SO, i think

but since you are asking for some help getting started, and i think that you will be back when you have developed some code.

start by developing the "enhancement" to the email that is sent out

how does the hidden text relate to the BCC field in the reply?

is the BCC field always the same?

does the "hidden text" have to be invisible at a glance, or can it be "unreadable" like a GUID for example ... 24DD18D4-C902-497F-A64B-28B2FA741661

put the "hidden text" in a table, if possible, separate from any other tables, if possible

it is easiest to look for a table in an email message

to hide it you could use white text on white background, and a text box on top of it

or make it very small

putting the "hidden text" in message headers may cause issues if the email server removes the headers ( i have read somewhere that it happens )

hopefuly this helps you some

Comment: Thanks for the constructive reply @jsotola - The hidden text is concated SQL side & then ends up hidden via <div style>="display:none;">BCC:stings goes here</div> I've since written the VBA with an if statement based on the subject, the BCC addresses (to answer your question are never the same) are then plucked from the bottom of the mail & populate the BCC field in Outlook.